# How do I get screen height minus the actionbar?

Tags: android, android-layout, height, android-screen, android-window

When I have the phone in landscape I'm wondering how I can get the pixel height of the screen not including the actionbar. So the pixel height of the actual viewable area. I want this so I can size a `GridLayout` appropriately. The `GridLayout` is inside of a `LinearLayout` so if I could get the pixel height of the `LinearLayout` that should work too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Calculate the entire height:

```
public static int getScreenHeight(Activity activity) {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    return metrics.heightPixels;
}
```

and deduct Action Bar height from it:

```
public static int getActionBarHeight(Context context) {
    int[] textSizeAttr = new int[]{R.attr.actionBarSize};
    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(new TypedValue().data,  textSizeAttr);
    int height = a.getDimensionPixelSize(0, 0);
    a.recycle();
    return height;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use [`View#getGlobalVisibleRect(Rect)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getGlobalVisibleRect(android.graphics.Rect)) to get the coordinates of a particular view on the screen.

```
    layout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final Rect rect = new Rect();
            layout.getGlobalVisibleRect(rect);

            final int height = rect.height();
        }
    });
```